# Can a Nen user still use their abilities after Kuroro Lucifer steals it?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

When Kuroro Lucifer steals the ability of another nen user, does it mean that the original user wont be able to use it anymore? Or is it like a copy-paste, like Ging copy-pasting the punching abilities? Because in the last arc, he was using Shalnark's ability 'Black voice'.

Does it mean the original user can't use it anymore? Can Chrollo give back the nen abilities that he stole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to his ***[wiki](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Chrollo_Lucilfer)*** page they do not have access to the ability anymore. Unfortunately, it is not stated wether or not he can give the skill back. It is probably safe to assume he would not give it back due to his status as leader of the ***[Gen'ei Ryodan.](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Troupe)***

> Chrollo's Nen ability allows him to steal the Hatsu of other people to use them as his own using a conjured book known as the "Bandit's Secret." **The theft victim, of course, no longer has access to their stolen ability.** The theft happens under strict conditions:
>
> 1.He must witness the Nen ability in action with his eyes.
>
> 2.He must ask about the ability and be answered by the victim.
>
> 3.His victim's palm must touch the handprint on the cover of Bandit's Secret.
>
> 4.All of the above must be done within an hour.

Answer (score 0):

He is able to give the ability back, or at least he has convinced Shalnark he can, as he asks Shalnark during a phone call whether he needs his ability (black voice) back.

Answer (score 0):

Nostrade’s daughter lost her ability to tell people’s fortunes after Chrollo stole it, so I think its safe to assume that people lose their abilities once he steals them. I am not sure whether or not he can return them.